# Looking for JQM Friendly Search with Tag Suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, search, tags

I am looking for Jquery Mobile Suggestions search. Here is a lisst of ones that I've tried

[Tag Handler](http://ioncache.github.io/Tag-Handler/#examples)
Failed because of JQM Initialization takes over the tagging structure, and destroys the pre-defined CSS.  Haven't found a way to run something like $(selector).trigger('destroy?');
[Tag-It](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) 
Failed because it lagged horribly on mobile devices when the user typed inside the box
[Tag-Manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3) 
Also lagged like crazy when the user typed inside the box.

I need something specificly that will display search items as "Tags" and give suggestions, I've been looking some of the following up in docs, and I really like the search bar if there is any sort of plugin

[Documentation for JQM Search - Not Applicable but interesting read](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-search-filtertext.html) I really don't want to load another library (IE loading UI on top of JQM) it would be nice, but its too heavy for a mobile device to load all these libraries in this case.

Comment: For tag Handler did you try setting data-role="none" on the ul element: <ul id="tag_handler" data-role="none"></ul>?

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I did try that first, I was thinking of going into the JS file and putting it on manually for the input box that gets dynamically placed, but also was hoping for a more obvious solution that google is not showing me... That process seems a little complicated for hopefully... a simpler task.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) is the most compatible and applicable for JQM, it seems to come together very quickly and there is a decent amount of documentation.  I am still trying new ones as I come across them.

List of All Known:

1. http://www.iog3.com/322/so_tag-tagging-system-based-on-stackoverflows-tag-search/
2. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
3. https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit
4. https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input
5. https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/
6. http://nicolasbize.github.com/magicsuggest/
7. http://ioncache.github.com/Tag-Handler/
8. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryTagEditor
9. http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/
10. http://textextjs.com/
11. http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tagging.php